# Timeout value in powerbi service

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset for 3 days I can not update it on Power BI service, knowing that on DESKTOP it is normally updated in 30 minutes. the dataset is powered from a SQL server database, via a data gateway. the data gateway is well updated. the incremental update is activated and the dataset retrieves only the data of the last 3 days to each update.

Here is the generated error message :

Data source error: The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed. Timeout value: 17998 sec.
Cluster URI: WABI-WEST-EUROPE-B-PRIMARY-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Activity ID: 680ec1d7-edea-4d7c-b87e-859ad2dee192
Application ID: fcde3b0f-874b-9321-6ee4-e506b0782dac
Time: 2020-12-24 19:03:30Z

What is the solution to this problem please.

Thank you

Comment: Check the region of the power bi report. Maybe a network issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What license are you using?

Without premium capacity, the max dataset size can be 1GB. Maybe your dataset size has crossed this mark? If you are using the shared capacity, then you can check the workspace utilized storage size by clicking on ellipses at top right corner. Then click on storage to see how much is utilized for that workspace.

Also note that in shared capacity there is a 10GB uncompressed dataset limit at the gateway (but this should not be an issue as you have only 3 day data in refesh)

Also check whether your power query query is foldable (on the final step you should be able to see the 'show native query' option). If not then incremental refresh does not work and results in querying the entire data.

Also, note that 17998 sec means 5 hours. What is your internet speed?